# Can ArangoDB be installed on Snow Leopard without using homebrew? If so, how?

Tags: xcode, macos, gcc, homebrew, arangodb

I've got an old Mac. Soon enough I will be trading up for a new PC but until then, I cannot upgrade my Mac OS, so I am stuck with Snow Leopard. Is there a way to install ArangoDB. I've tried several times via terminal, but gcc does not want to compile and gives me following errors:

```
Checking if C++ compiler "/usr/bin/llvm-g++" is GCC... yes
Checking if C compiler "/usr/bin/llvm-gcc" is GCC... yes
Checking if C compiler is GCC 4.8.2 or newer...no
Checking if C++ compiler is GCC 4.8.2 or newer...no
ERROR: Refusing to build with compiler that does not meet requirements
```

Also, I cannot seem to upgrade gcc to version above 4.2 because of old Xcode. So if anyone knows how to achieve this without uninstalling my Xcode, that would surely help. Thanks.

Comment: Try to find older version of arangodb which builds with your compiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to @fceller's answer, would be to install [Boot2Docker](http://boot2docker.io/) on your Mac and run an [ArangoDB Docker container](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb-docker).

Comment: This looks interesting. I've never used Docker before. Are the containers isolated or can I connect to them from outside? I guess what I'm asking is, do they function like a server that I can then add to my stack on my own OS, or is it more like Vagrant, a VM Box with it's own isolated environment?

Comment: Essentially they work like issolated OS-processes with an IP Address. They can be totally isolated from the host or accessble, according to your needs. In your case (As in my case, using Windows), using Boot2Docker you are essentially creating a Docker Host (Using VirtualBox) inside your physical host, to run the Docker containers. This happens, because the Docker host has some minimum requirements (mostly Linux with Kernel >= 3.10, depending on flavour).

Comment: Thanks. I've been reading up on this. This is exactly what I'm looking for. Do you know if I can take the containers, upload them to a shared hosting and run them? Would they work on production deployment. Based on the literature and tech talks I've seen, it looks like it might but I haven't seen a definitive answer. Essentially, could I run the my entire Docker setup on a production website? Thank you again so much, I did not know this existed.

Comment: Glad to have helped, Ismael. :)
Short answer: on the shared hosting Yes, but it depends and yes to the production site setup (inc. cloud instances).
Long answer:
There are a few things you must be careful about such as where you want to store your data, in the host or in other container(s). If you store it in another container, you have of course to be careful, not to accidentally remove it, etc...
If the requirements are fulfilled, I don't see why it would not work. The Docker site has plenty of docs to get you started with hosting on. I had to invest some time in learning, but it paid off :)

Comment: It's a huge save because you can do a lot of automation and also allows  a level of clustering. See https://docs.docker.com/compose/ and https://docs.docker.com/swarm/

Comment: Life saver. Yes, thank you. This technology is insane. This questions was actually last ditch effort to having to go with something like Vagrant, which is great but has too much overhead. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The ArangoDB databases requires a working C++ 11 compiler. One way to compile it without homebrew is to first compile GCC 4.9, see for instance https://solarianprogrammer.com/2013/06/11/compiling-gcc-mac-os-x/

Comment: I was looking for an article with this info but it seems kinda messy solution even for a testing environment. Still, I'll bookmark it and turn back to it, if nothing else works, this probably will. Thank you.